# set app to iphone4 and up,and ios6

Tags: xcode

I have 3 questions that i couldnt find an answer to.

1. How would i set my app to work ONLY with iPhones-4 and up ?
2. How can i install in my xcode  ios6 to check my app ?
3. do i need icon in 57x57 if my app is for iphone4 and up only ?

thanks .

Comment: Adding some random code does not make it a "quality question".

Comment: @MartinR and not adding the code, would not allow me to upload almost anything to this site . i dont think this question has some problem. its relevant,specific,and right.

Comment: I removed this random code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1. This is not possible, even if you detect iPhone model in your code, someone can buy your app on older iPhone (3GS if you build your app for iOS 6).
You should support all devices available on a given iOS version.

Ad 2. Install the newest XCode (4.5.1) from Mac AppStore

Ad 3. Yes, you do.